# Does the iPhone use the .vcf to store the address book data?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, webdav, addressbook

I want to ask a question about the iPhone address book. I am writing a program, it relates to the CardDav server and the .vcf file. I want to use the NSURLConnection to connect the server and download the .vcf. However, I am not sure that the iPhone can read and write the .vcf file or not.

One thing I can sure that is the sharing function. When I click the contacts and click one of the cells, and scroll down the screen, there are 'share contact' button. When I click the button, it will send a .vcf file to other.

Therefore, I would like to ask that is it possible to

1) download .vcf from a CardDav server and

2) add the contact from .vcf to iPhone contacts book

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) Yes thats possible, infact its the default action when you open a .vcf file on a iOS device.

Comment: S, thank you for your reply. Are there some API or library I can use to do it for the 2)? Would you mind to provide some reference or examples? thank you.